# Change push notification text in android

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, onesignal

I have created a xamarin app, and I want to edit the text of a push notification text before it gets displayed to the user.

I am using a  Notification Extenstion Service and also OneSingal library to get the notifications.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Com.OneSignal.Android;
using MyApp.Shared.Utility;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
[Service(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
[IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" })]
public class CustomNotificationExtenderService : NotificationExtenderService
{
    private OSNotificationReceivedResult _result;
    private NotificationManager notifyManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, "1");
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent){ }
    protected override bool OnNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult p0)
    {
        _result = p0;
        var body = "New Encrypted Message";

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, "1");
        
        builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Logo);
        builder.SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(body));
        builder.SetContentTitle("New Message");
        builder.SetContentText(body);
        // Build the notification and display it
        notifyManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Please note that in my sample code above I have omitted the logic for the creation of text that goes in the notification banner. I was expecting to see a push Notification with a text 'New Encrypted Message'. But it shows the actual message that sends from the server.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Is this line not working? builder.SetContentTitle("New Message"); And you can remove builder.SetContentTitle("New Message");

Comment: It does not work. It still show the message from server

Answer (score 0):

If need to show custom message, you could have a try with overriding a **NotificationCompat.Builder** and return it to **OverrideSettings**.

Sample code as follow:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationDisplayedResult;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationPayload;
import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedResult;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationExtenderExample extends NotificationExtenderService {
   @Override
   protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
      OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
      overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
         @Override
         public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
            //Force remove push from Notification Center after 30 seconds
            builder.setTimeoutAfter(30000);
            // Sets the icon accent color notification color to Green on Android 5.0+ devices.
            builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF00FF00", 16).intValue());
            builder.setContentTitle("New Message");
            builder.setContentText("New Encrypted Message");
            return builder;
         }
      };

      OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
      Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Notification displayed with id: " + displayedResult.androidNotificationId);

      // Return true to stop the notification from displaying.
      return false;
   }
}
```

More info can refer to [OneSignal Service Extensions document](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#setup).

Comment: This does not work. I already spoke with one signal engineers. There is an exception thrown at line overridesettings.extender

Comment: @LibinJoseph Okey, got it. If other solution will update here later.

Answer (score 0):

Every notification comes in 2 way. 1 is application is in foreground and other is application is in background. If app is in background than notification is handled by itself either by Google or iOS.

If your code is not executing it means you are checking for background notification.

If you want that your code must be executed in all the way either background or foreground than you should use silent push notification.

For push notification you have to do nothing. It is backend side code. In backend they have to send payload as `'data' => $data` instead of `'notification' => $data` and for ios 1 extra thing need to add is `'content-available' => '1'`

For more reference you can check [this link](http://www.coding4developers.com/php/ios-push-notifications-in-php/) which is for php backend. Syntax may be different for other backend server.

Comment: The code that I have written is for a notification service, which means to handle it in background. Its nothing to do in server side, the notification service extension is all working good in ios

Comment: Can you check it is not working in background or also not working for foreground.